# Hide camera device name from windows applications with MS Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, dll, com, directshow, ms-media-foundation

### Context

I am trying to build an image filter application where, the application will get the user's selected camera frames, apply some filters on the frames, create a virtual camera device and send the frame to that virtual camera. I am successful in doing all of these except I have to hide the actual camera device because it is being used by my application and other applications (suppose zoom/meet) should see my virtual camera instead of the actual camera device.

I have become able to create a virtual camera and send frames there with the help of [obs-virtual-cam](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam)'s `obs-virtualsource.dll`.

### Desired Outcome

I need to create some kind of wrapper for device enumeration DLL from Microsoft. Once my wrapper is registered, it will modify the list of devices returning by the system to the applications. The settings can be saved in Registry and invoked in the context of other processes.

### Answer I want

I am proficient at C/C++ but newbie in COM and MS Media Foundation API. So, even if the problem cannot be solved right here in the answer, I welcome and link or guidance to get started in the right direction to solve this specific problem.

Comment: If you don't register your virtual camera to the Filter Mapper (avoid calling https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam/blob/master/src/virtual-source/dllmain.cpp#L157), you can still instantiate your COM objects directly. In fact, depending on how you code your app, you may not even need to register your COM objects as COM objects but instantiate them in C/C++

Comment: I don't see obs-virtual-cam even exposed to Media Foundation. Media Foundation apps should not be even able to see virtual device, so there is no question of altering enumeration in first place.

Comment: One possible solution IMHO, could be to SetWindowsHookEx into each process and hook the MFEnumDeviceSources API (using minhook for instance). This might be harder for UWP applications, but not impossible. Chrome and FireFox also use some sandboxing that needs to be tackled to hook the Media Foundation calls. This would require some COM knowledge though.

Comment: `obs-virtual-cam` is in the question just to provide context. I think it is not relevant to the answer I am looking for. To be in a few words, I want "to hide a camera device name from applications".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Media Foundation API does not offer you means to hide cameras for applications. Neither for application that use Media Foundation to access the cameras, nor specifically for applications that access cameras without Media Foundation.

Comment: So how to achieve that then?